# JS double forEach unexpected result

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have Array:

```
[
  { 
    name: 'Bob',
    nestedArray: [ { param: '' }, { param: ''}, ... ]
  },
  { 
    name: 'Alise',
    nestedArray: [ { param: '' }, { param: ''}, ... ]
  },
  { 
    name: 'Rony',
    nestedArray: [ { param: '' }, { param: ''}, ... ]
  },

  ....

]
```

Need to make Array.nestedArray.param = Array.name

I do:

```
Array.forEach((arrayElement) => {
  arrayElement.nestedArray.forEach((nestedArrayElement) => {
    console.log(arrayElement.name);
    nestedArrayElement.param = arrayElement.name;
  });
});

console.log(Array);
```

Checking resulting Array I get param equal to 'Rony' (last iterated arrayElement) **in all nestedArrays**. But the string

```
console.log(arrayElement.name);
```

always returns expected value ('Bob', 'Alise', 'Rony')

I tried index access also to read and write.

Help me please. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You must be doing something else. When I run your exact code I get the expected outcome

Comment: Is your array really called `Array`? You may want to call it something else as `Array` is already used by native Javascript.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/sn8h5Lzk/1/

Comment: No it's called not Array it's just to be clear in my explanations.

Comment: I think the problem is with the way you constructed `Array`. I'll bet all the objects in `nestedArray` are the same object, not new objects.

Comment: It works fine if you use literals as you show in the question.

Comment: The problem was in how I managed to create "nestedArray" – it was an array containing links to same object.
So each time it was manipulations with same object here:
     nestedArrayElement.param = arrayElement.name;

Thanks to everybody trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly:

```
var arr = [
  { name: 'Bob', nestedArray: [{ param: '' }, { param: ''}] },
  { name: 'Alice', nestedArray: [{ param: '' }, { param: ''}] },
  { name: 'Rony', nestedArray: [{ param: '' }, { param: ''}] },
];

for (var i in arr) {
    for (var j in arr[i].nestedArray) {
    arr[i].nestedArray[j].param = arr[i].name;
  }
}
```

Edit:
Fixed the code per @napilnik's comment. As far as not using `for-in`, it doesn't change the basic idea and can be decided by the developer once he/she knows the consequence.

Comment: last string: arr[i].nestedArray[j].param = arr[i].name;

Comment: A good answer should explain what's wrong with the original code and how you've fixed the problems.

Comment: It's generally not considered a good idea to use `for-in` on arrays. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea?lq=1

Comment: You still haven't explained what the OP's problem is and why your solution fixes it. What's wrong with using `forEach` that's solved by using `for-in`?